# how to change the SQL script so that the columns with the amount are right-aligned

Tags: sql-server, xml

Please help me change the request so that the columns with the amount are right-aligned? They are tagged AS 'money'. I will be using dynamic SQL, so the fields will change. It is important for me that whatever field is not marked with the money tag, is shifted to the right and everything else is centered.
I am using this script. Below is the result that I expect.

```
  insert into #a 
  Values (1, 'GB', 2000),
         (2, 'DE', 170),
         (3, 'PT', 960)


    DECLARE @Values             NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @Values = CAST((SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserID)  AS 'td','',
                        (SELECT CONCAT('https://backend.com/User/UserDetails.aspx?UserID=',UserId) AS [@href],UserID FOR XML PATH('a'),TYPE) AS 'td',''
                       ,Country AS 'td',''
                       ,TotalDeposits AS 'money',''
    FROM  #a
    FOR XML PATH('tr'),ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    
    select '<html><body><table border=1 cellpadding=10 style="border-collapse:collapse;">' +  + @Values + '</table></body></html>'
```

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table border=1 cellpadding=10 style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr align="center" valign="center">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="https://backend.com/User/UserDetails.aspx?UserID=1">
            <UserID>1</UserID>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>GB</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;">2000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center" valign="center">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
          <a href="https://backend.com/User/UserDetails.aspx?UserID=2">
            <UserID>2</UserID>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>DE</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;">170</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center" valign="center">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
          <a href="https://backend.com/User/UserDetails.aspx?UserID=3">
            <UserID>3</UserID>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>PT</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;">960</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like you should be using an actual application to generate your email, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an easy task for XQuery.

Benefits:

- No strings concatenation.
- No worries for NULL values.
- Very easy to create, very easy to maintain.
- UI styling is controlled via CSS.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (UserID INT PRIMARY KEY, Country CHAR(2), TotalDeposits MONEY, IsMoney BIT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (UserID, Country, TotalDeposits, IsMoney) VALUES
(1, 'GB', 2000, 0),
(2, 'DE', 170, 1),
(3, 'PT', 960, 0)
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @xhtmlBody XML
   , @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
   , @tableCaption VARCHAR(30) = 'Users list';

SET @xhtmlBody = (SELECT (
SELECT * FROM @tbl FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root'))
.query('<html><head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            (: including embedded CSS styling :)
            <style>
            table <![CDATA[ {border-collapse: collapse;  width: 300px;} ]]>
            th <![CDATA[ {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} ]]>
            th, td <![CDATA[ { text-align: left; padding: 8px;} ]]>
            tr:nth-child(even) <![CDATA[ {background-color: #f2f2f2;} ]]>
            #green <![CDATA[ {background-color: lightgreen;} ]]>
         </style>
         </head>
         <body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
   <caption><h2>{sql:variable("@tableCaption")}</h2></caption>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>UserID</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>TotalDeposits</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
{
    for $row in /root/row
    let $pos := count(root/row[. << $row]) + 1
    return <tr align="center" valign="center">
            <td>{$pos}</td>
            <td><a href="{concat(''https://backend.com/User/UserDetails.aspx?UserID='',data($row/UserID[1]))}">
                        <UserID>{data($row/UserID)}</UserID>
                    </a></td>
            <td>{data($row/Country)}</td>
            <td style="{concat(if (data($row/IsMoney="1")) then "text-align:right;"
                else "text-align:left;", "vertical-align:middle;")}">{data($row/TotalDeposits)}</td>
        </tr>
}
</tbody></table></body></html>'));

SELECT @xhtmlBody;

SET @body = CAST(@xhtmlBody AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

**Output**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
            table  {border-collapse: collapse;  width: 300px;} 
            th  {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} 
            th, td  { text-align: left; padding: 8px;} 
            tr:nth-child(even)  {background-color: #f2f2f2;} 
            #green  {background-color: lightgreen;} 
         </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <caption>
        <h2>Users list</h2>
      </caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>UserID</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>TotalDeposits</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr align="center" valign="center">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://backend.com/User/UserDetails.aspx?UserID=1">
              <UserID>1</UserID>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>GB</td>
          <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;">2000.0000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center" valign="center">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://backend.com/User/UserDetails.aspx?UserID=2">
              <UserID>2</UserID>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>DE</td>
          <td style="text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;">170.0000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center" valign="center">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://backend.com/User/UserDetails.aspx?UserID=3">
              <UserID>3</UserID>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>PT</td>
          <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;">960.0000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very neat approach. Which version of SQL Server is it compatible with?

Comment: thank you very much! Can I use it with dynamic SQL if I need different fields from the @tbl table every time?

Comment: @ThomasDoconski, XQuery is available starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards.

Comment: @Zorge17, you can always use dynamic SQL. Just it will need some tinkering. But XQuery will enforce a proper (X)HTML.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky,  I am using your solution and it helped me a lot. One question about filling every even line with gray (tr:nth-child(even)  {background-color: #f2f2f2;} ). When I paste Output into notepad, this fill is there, but when I send mail from the SQL server msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail it disappears. Do you know what this might be related to?

Comment: The best way to test it is to save the `@body` variable on the file system as an *.html file, open it in internet browser, and test it .