# SQL sending email with data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to send a table via email in a table like shape. What I mean is to style nicely the text that I am receiving in email, because now it looks ugly, not like a table. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testEmail]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SubjectText VARCHAR(100) = 'Day ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,(CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())))
    DECLARE @tab char(1) = CHAR(9); 

    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
                    @query = 'SELECT IDDruzyny, nazwa FROM TEST.dbo.Druzyna',
                    @body = '
                <html>
                <body>
                <br/><b><font color=red>Hiho</font></b>
                </body>
                </html>
            ',                                                              
    @Body_format = 'HTML',                                                  
    @subject = @SubjectText,
    @profile_name = 'SIT',  
    @recipients = 'safemail@onet.eu',   
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 0,
    @query_result_separator = @tab,
    @query_result_header = 1
    END
END
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code is product specific. (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: Yes MS SQL Server. I dont have idea. I just want to split the data so it looks like a table

Comment: If you want to show data in a table in the mail, you should make in the mail body, i suggest to use [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) while building you query.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) a documentation how to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70202422/how-to-change-the-sql-script-so-that-the-columns-with-the-amount-are-right-align